# (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a style sheet that has some css3 media queries in it.

```
@media (max-width: 480px), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    p, label, .labelish {font-size: 1.2em;}
    h3 {font-size: 1.4em;}
        body{
         background-color: red !important;
        }
}
```

Now I understand the first part which is only apply these styles if the users browsers is below 480px. The `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5` is what I'm not getting. I understand it's looking for high density screen pixel resolution. But not sure why it's kicking in on the new Mac retina screens on Chrome. The reason I ask is I have 2 computers one with the new retina screen and the other without and the above css is kicking in only on the retina screen.

I found this link http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/ which lists out the screens it should effect

- Google Nexus S
- Samsung Galaxy S II
- HTC Desire
- HTC Desire HD
- HTC Incredible S
- HTC Velocity
- HTC Sensation

According to this list Mac retina screens should not be applying these styles.

Can someone explain why this is occurring.

Comment: maybe your comma is disturbing? `@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 950px) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this property works like the rest of CSS, then `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5;` should be applied to devices with this ratio reported as 2 - in the same way that `max-width: 480px;` will be appliet do devices with width  of 320px

also comma (`,`) is an OR operator when it comes to CSS selectors / lists, use [AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries#and) instead if that was your intention:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)
```